# Jenkins Deployment Issue

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to deploy war file into tomcat.Build is success but giving FileNotFound exception.I'm using tomcat7.I found some references in google but didn't get the solution

Comment: which plugin are you using for deployment and please give more details

Comment: deploy war/ear to container.My tomcat server has a public url. https://tomcat.xyz.com

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy war from build server to tomacat server ,use robocopy to copy war to tomcat server

robocopy c:abc/abc.war  //tomcatserver and path

Answer (score 0):

Most containers have a directory where you can "place" the war, in order to deploy it.

Therefore in Jenkins you can set up Send build artifacts over SSH
More

On configuring the server, you should go in Configure Jenkins -> Configure system -> SSH Servers

Add the server you need to deploy to, username (+password) and Remote directory: /opt/app/tomcat/webapps (or whatever)

More info here - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin